# How to write a raw DQL query in Symfony Form Type file

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've searched this for a while but cannot find a definitive answer.

I need to write a query in the `__construct` function of a FormType in my Symfony CRM, but when I try to pass the `EntityRepository` class in the `__construct` argument I get the following error:

> Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Form\CampAttendeeAddType::__construct()
>   must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository, none given

Here is my code:

```
use \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class CampAttendeeAddType extends AbstractType
{

    public function __construct(EntityRepository $er)
    {
        $camp_id = $_GET['id'];
        $query = $er->createQuery('
            SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AppBundle:CampAttendee ca WHERE ca.nonRider = 1 AND ca.campId = ' . $camp_id);
        $non_riders = $query->getOneOrNullResult();

    }
...
```

I also tried declaring it explicitly in the function:

```
$er = new EntityRepository();
```

But all I get is:

> Missing argument 1 for Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::__construct()

It seems I cannot win!

I need to be able to do this to determine the choices passed to the following field:

```
$builder->add('non_rider', ChoiceType::class,
    array(
        'label' => 'Is Non-Rider',
        'required' => true,
        'placeholder' => '-- Please select --',
        'choices' => array(
            'Yes' => 1,
            'No' => 0
        ),
        'label_attr' => array(
            'class' => 'control-label'
        ),
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control required'
        )
    ));
```

As once the limit is reached, the 'Yes' choice needs to be replaced by a disabled note that reads something like 'You have reached the limit' so no more can be added.

Is this something that is possible, and how can it be done if so?

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html#accessing-services-and-config Just be aware that only one instance of each form type is ever created.  And pay attention to the note about tagging.

Comment: I'm afraid you are just going to have to take some time and read the docs.  Make sure the doc version matches your Symfony version.

Comment: Two ways I can think of that might solve this...use a form event to override the options with a disabled version when your conditions are met. Using query_builder of the FormType but you'd need a phantom/temporary table view with the YES/NO options and JOIN that to the CampAttendee table(s) with the conditional tests required to render the options accordingly. The former is likely much easier.

https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#form-events-underlying-data